# Why can't my Android app read from storage?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest, android-external-storage

I am relatively new to Android, and I am trying to integrate a file explorer into my app. I am using this library, added via maven repository: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2690

I have included the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in my manifest file, yet for some reason, my app reads the entirety of external storage as being an empty directory, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why!

When I use another app, like ES File Explorer for example, and navigate to **the same directory**, it is not even close to empty! The directory is not empty, and other apps can read from it, but not mine, for some reason.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="datashift.mat.datashiftnfc.MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff0000">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dsheader"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose File"
        android:id="@+id/browseButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:onClick="openFilePicker"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package datashift.mat.datashiftnfc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.nbsp.materialfilepicker.ui.FilePickerActivity;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openFilePicker(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FilePickerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(FilePickerActivity.ARG_SHOW_HIDDEN, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String filePath = data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH);
            File file=new File(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="datashift.mat.datashiftnfc"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to read the file? In this sample code you are simply creating a file object, but doing nothing with it. If you want to read from a file, you need an input stream:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis), 64 * 1024);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
reader.close();
```

If you target API 23 you have to ask the user for read/write permission to access external storage as well.

Comment: The library opens a file Explorer which should display all files in the directory, and the file object is the file the user selects from that Explorer, but the Explorer shows external storage as empty.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but you can try to use the standard Android intents to show a file picker:

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

Comment: Do you have any resources I could read on that subject? That's what I wanted to do at first but I couldn't figure out how

Comment: There isn't much more than what I wrote above, you send the intent with ACTION_GET_CONTENT and specify the mime type for your file type. Then you get the result in onActivityResult, just like in your code. The file is in the data (type intent) in onActivityResult, you get the file using String filePath = data.getData().getPath();

You can see an example here: http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html

Comment: I have it almost working with your suggestion. It can now see the files, however the files are grayed out and I cannot select them. Any idea why? I have included the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Nevermind; like you said, I have to ask for permission on API 23; I went into settings and the permission was turned off. How can I detect if the permission is turned off and ask the user to turn it on?

Comment: hmm... even after requesting and granting permission, everything is still grayed out.

Comment: I got it working based on your suggestions. Chosen as correct answer and upvoted.